# Looking for non-blocking spring kafka ErrorHandler

Tags: spring-kafka

After use of SeekToCurrentErrorHandler i am looking for a non-blocking kafka ErrorHandler. Because of some unstable subsystems we need to set high interval times as 5 minutes or more. Which would block our processing.

My idea is to use the topic itself to re-queue failing messages. But with two additional header values `kafka_try-counter` and `kafka_try-timestamp`.

Based on the `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` and the `DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer` i implemented a draft of `RePublishingErrorHandler` and a `RePublishingRecoverer`

The `RePublishingRecoverer` update the kafka headers and produce the message in the same topic.
The `RePublishingErrorHandler` check header values and if `kafka_try-counter` exeeds max-attempts calls another `ConsumerRecordRecoverer` like the DLT or Logging.

The `kafka_try-timestamp` used determine the wait time of a message. If it returns to fast it should re-queued without the incremention of the try-counter.

The expectation of this aproach is to get a non-blocking listener.

Because of i am new to spring-kafka implementation and also kafka itself. I'm not sure if this aproach is OK.

And i am also somehow stuck in the implementation of that concept.

Answer (score 0):

> My idea is to use the topic itself to re-queue failing messages.

That won't work; you would have to publish it to another topic and have a (delaying) consumer on that topic, perhaps polling at some interval rather than using a message-driven consumer. Then have that consumer publish it back to the original topic.

All of this assumes that strict ordering within a partition is not a requirement for you.

It's easy enough to subclass the `DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer` and override the `createProducerRecord()` method. Call `super()` and then add your headers.

Set the `BackOff` in the `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` to have a zero back off and 0 retries to immediately publish to the DLT.

Comment: Is the use of another topic just because of the delaying?

Comment: If you want non-blocking on the main consumer and there are only a few records in the topic you could end up in a tight loop. You could mitigate that with some consumer properties, but it would be hard to tune it for all circumstances to avoid wasting CPU and network resources.

Comment: The kafka_try-timestamp header should handle this somehow. For instance if a message falls and its a timestamp+delay is in the future, so it reprocessed to early the handler can switch into blocking mode, wait until the time is reached and than push the message back into the queue.

Comment: Well, then that's not a non-blocking consumer. Records behind this one in the partition will not be received, so that's a different requirement; you can do that blocking in the listener itself. Even worse, if the consumer is assigned multiple partitions, they will be suspended too. I don't think we want this unusual logic in a standard error handler.

Comment: I'm sure you are right. But first I have to understand what partitions are for in this context.

Comment: Partitions are used in increase consumer concurrency; one partition can only be consumed by one consumer (in the same consumer group) at a time. If 2 consumers have different group ids, they will both get all the records in their assigned partitions. Generally, you will need at least as many partitions as consumers, but often many more partitions than consumers so you can scale out your consumers later.